If Fighting Initiate with Unarmed Fighting Style replaces the damage of a Monk's unarmed strike, does it replace the damage of a Radiant Sun Bolt?
If a Sun Soul Monk takes the Fighting Initiate feat and chooses Unarmed Fighting Style, thus replacing the usual damage of their unarmed strike with d6 (or d8 if wielding no weapons or shield), would this also replace the damage of their Radiant Sun Bolt, since that deals the same damage as their Martial Arts die?

I think this question could be improved if you said why you think Unarmed Fighting might apply to Radiant Sun Bolt.

No by RAW
The "Unarmed Fighting" Fighting Style specifically calls out that it changes your unarmed strikes, not your Martial Arts die.
Unarmed Fighting, TCoE p. 42:

Your unarmed strikes can deal bludgeoning damage equal to 1d6 + your Strength modifier on a hit. If you aren't wielding any weapons or a shield when you make the attack roll, the d6 becomes a d8.

Radiant Sun Bolt isn't an unarmed strike, it's some other attack that just happens to use your Martial Arts die, which is not affected by the "Unarmed Fighting" Fighting Style.
Radiant Sun Bolt, XGtE p. 35:

You gain a new attack option that you can use with the Attack action. The special attack is a ranged spell attack with a range of 30 feet. You are proficient with it, and you add your Dexterity modifier to its attack and damage rolls. Its damage is radiant, and its damage die is a d4. This die changes as you gain monk levels, as shown in the Martial Arts column of the Monk table.

